# Get MimeEntity from MimeMessage

Tags: c#, smime, mimekit

I have an application that needs to parse emails, which may be encrypted or not. I have the complete flow working fine for emails that are encrypted, but the ones that are not encrypted are giving me trouble as I would like to use the same code once the email has been decrypted for what I am doing. When the email was not encrypted I have a MimeMessage, I need to cast this into a MimeEntity somehow for it to go through the parsing code that I have written for the encrypted messages.

Here is a sample of my code, notice

```
var pkcs7 = message.BodyParts.OfType<ApplicationPkcs7Mime>().FirstOrDefault();
MimeEntity decrypted;
if (pkcs7 != null)
{
    decrypted = decryptAndValidateEmail(pkcs7, certLocation, certPassword);
}
else
{
    //********************//
    //THIS is the code that is not working at this point

    decrypted = message.BodyParts as MimeEntity; 

    //********************//
}

var decryptedParts = new List<MimePart>();
if (decrypted is Multipart)
{
    decryptedParts = breakMultiPart((Multipart)decrypted);
}
else if (decrypted is MimePart)
{
    decryptedParts.Add((MimePart)decrypted);
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown Mime part found");
}


var textParts = decryptedParts.Where(r => r is TextPart);
var htmlParts = textParts.Where(x => ((TextPart)x).IsHtml);
var textBodyParts = textParts.Where(x => !((TextPart)x).IsHtml);
var attachmentParts = decryptedParts.Where(r => !(r is TextPart));

if (htmlParts.Any())
{
    if (htmlParts.Count() > 1)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("multiple html body parts.");
    }
    var htmlPart = (TextPart)htmlParts.First();
   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
decrypted = message.Body as MimeEntity;
```

The `BodyParts` property is an `IEnumerable<MimeEntity>` which is why casting it to a `MimeEntity` wasn't working for you.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a MultiPart and add all the parts to it and then cast as a Mime Entity? (I will not be back to my work computer till Tuesday to give it a try.)

Comment: why would you do that?

Comment: As the code that I have already written to do the parsing of the message is expecting 1 Mime Entity, if I can get this into a MultiPart, it will allow me to use that exact same code twice and limit the potential issues from having the same code in two places.

Comment: `MimeMessage.Body` is *already* a `MimeEntity` and, if the message is more than a single-part message (i.e. has more than just a text body such as attachments, etc), then the `MimeMessage.Body` is *already* a `Multipart` so no need to add them to a *new* `Multipart`.

Comment: That does work. Thank you, I was confused and didn't know that the attachments would be in the body. Thank you.